# Add multiple classes to an element using .attr?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently trying to add multiple classes from a variable created when the user selects checkboxes to an element using $('.element').attr but this doesn't seem to be working so far - this method seems to be only getting the first class in the array, .addClass works only to add the classes and not remove them.

Is there any workaround to this?

The Code used is:

```
$('.ms-drop').on('change', function(){

        var val = [];

        var selectedItem  = $(this).find('input').attr('value');

        //get the values of each checked checkbox
        $(this).find('li > label > input:checked').each(function(i){
            val[i] = $(this).val();
        });

        var new_class = val.join(' ');

        console.log(new_class);

        $('.editable').attr('class', new_class);

        $('.writeHere').html(new_class);

});
```

Please see the link below to see it working:

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/vemeqosujune/6/)

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Include your code in the question; once that link dies, this question becomes useless to future readers with the same problem.

Comment: Imposible. two class in a tag? Like this: `<a class="" class=""`?

Comment: Would [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) be useful?

Comment: First, read the documentation. To add classes, don't use `.attr()`, use [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/).

Comment: Already tried toggleClass, it starts to add/remove the classes randomly.

Comment: You're replacing the class, not adding a class. you should use [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/)

Comment: Hendry, no - I don't want multiple class attributes, I want multipla classes inside the same attribute - something like `class="type1 type2 type3"`

Comment: Roamer - as I said, `addClass` works - but I also want to remove the classes that come out of the variable/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove all existing classes via `removeAttr()`, then add them using `addClass()`:

```
$('.editable').removeAttr('class');
$('.editable').addClass(new_class);
```

Which can be chained to just:

```
$('.editable').removeAttr('class').addClass(new_class);
```

*Your `join` code appears to work correctly and in theory `attr` will replace the classes. I actually suspect you have another issue going on.*

Actual issue: You are basically removing the class you are using to match the elements with you need to change the way you find them e.g add an id to that field instead:

```
 <div id="myedit" class="editable">
    Class: <span class="writeHere">Hehe</span>
  </div>
```

and change the way tyou access it from `$('.editable')` to:

```
$('#myedit').addClass...
```

Thanks for all the votes, but I actually think `Rhumborl`'s approach is cleaner and better for the problem specified. Please upvote his :)

Comment: when using addClass() method, simply the name of new_class would work.

Comment: The second line won't work. when it is executed `$('.editable')` will return an empty list as we've removed all classed from the elements and we can't re-select them by class.

Comment: You could also do method chaining `$('.editable').removeAttr('class').addClass(new_class);` as a syntatic sugar alternative ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I can see where my issue was - very helpful! :)

Answer (score 6):

I would listen to the `input onchange` instead and just use `toggleClass`:

```js
$('.ms-drop input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(){
  $('.editable').toggleClass($(this).val());
  $('.editable').html($('.editable').attr('class')); // for debug purposes
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <section class="ms-drop">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="Class1">
        </label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="Class2">
        </label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="Class3">
        </label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="Class4">
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  
  
  <div class="editable">
    Class: <span class="writeHere">Hehe</span>
  </div>
  
  
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT** If other code can change the style of `.editable` as @Roamer-1888  mentions, you can test the `checked` state of the box and decide to add or remove, rather than just toggle (although anything else changing the classes would make the checkboxes out of sync anyway which is a functional bug in itself):

```
$('.ms-drop input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked'))
    $('.editable').addClass($(this).val());
  else
    $('.editable').removeClass($(this).val());

  $('.editable').html($('.editable').attr('class')); // for debug purposes
});
```

Comment: +1: This solves the actual problem elegantly, not just the problem specified (unlike mine). This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie +1 for your comment.

Comment: I wouldn't do it this way. If any other code should add/remove one of the toggled classes to/from `.editable`, then the checkboxes will start to work in *antiphase* ... on will be off, and off will be on.

Comment: Similarly, you are a hostage to initial conditions.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 yes that may be possible, depending on the app - if you have a different solution, you can still post an answer

Comment: That's much better after the edit. And yes, it's correct to note that undisciplined adding/removal of classes will put the checkboxes out of sync. You could also mention that a disciplined approach would be to set a checkbox's state and trigger its onchange handler.

Comment: Actually all the answers are useless. Sometimes you really have to use attr not addClass